# java - Drawing multiple diagonal lines on a BufferedImage

Tags: java, image, draw

im trying to draw multiple diagonal lines across the whole image (leaving a space between them) i've used this code to draw horizontal and vertical lines:

```
for (int z = 1; z < partToCrop; z++) {
    Shape hLines = new Line2D.Float(0, cropInPartWidth*z, chunkWidth, cropInPartWidth*z);
    Shape vLines = new Line2D.Float(cropInPartHeight*z, 0, cropInPartHeight*z, chunkHeight);
    gr.draw(hLines); //gr is a BufferedImage
    gr.draw(vLines);
}
```

where

```
int partToCrop = 5;
float cropInPartWidth = imgWidth / partToCrop; 
float cropInPartHeight = imgHeight / partToCrop;
```

and works good. Now i need to draw multiple diagonal lines (i.e 4 diagonal lines) with 45° and -45° degrees of inclination across the whole image, hope you will help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
Shape firstLine = new Line2D.Float(0, imgHeight, imgWidth, 0); // this line is from bottom left to top right
Shape secondLine = new Line2D.Float(0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight); // this line is from top left to bot right
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually this seems easier to me.

Assuming `imgDim = imgHeight = imgWidth`:

```
int spacing = 2;

for (int z = 1; z < imgDim; z = z + spacing) 
{
    Shape dLines = new Line2D.Float(0, z, z, 0); 

    gr.draw(dLines); 
}
```

Comment: This is the output: [link](http://imageshack.com/a/img593/2373/xu0f.png)
but i need something like this: [link](http://imageshack.com/a/img38/8007/rhf.bmp)
where i can decide how many lines i need